# Ubuntu on a Sony xperia c1905? Can this be done?

Tags: system-installation, ubuntu-touch, android, sony

Is it at all possible to install Ubuntu touch or a more relevant Ubuntu operating system on a Sony xperia c1905 with android 4.3?
The intention being to fully reformat to Ubuntu.
Will I have full functionality?
Are there simple instructions for non-experts?
What might be common problems with installations?
Or is it not recommended as yet?
Many thanks in advance, and apologies if this has already been asked elsewhere, please post a link if so.

Answer (score 0):

Having just rooted a Xperia z, I know 4.3 can be rooted so you can put a different os on your phone from there.

Having said that only the nexus 4,5,7 and 10 are officially supported by ubuntu touch.

Unofficially a few Sony models have ports available you can get the full list here (https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Touch/Devices)

And at the bottom of the wiki you will see a link to xda which is the best place to find out if your device has a current working (unofficial) port. The last update for the Xperia z model was in 2013 so I'm not sure if you'll be able to.

Hope this helps in some way, I've typed this on my mobiles Web browser so sorry for any typos etc..

Comment: thank you very kindly.
however as a novice i'm been informed that there is no available port and that it may not be a great idea as a novice to attempt it.

i have also been informed via ubuntu forums of "lil debi" and something called chroot which dont mean anything to me as yet.
i dont see whay phones cant be like laptops or PC's and be as simple to reformat as they are.

Comment: Yeah theyre right i woudnt do it unless you dont care if you break your phone or you know what your doing. you could always buy a phone with ubuntu touch pre installed. you can get an offical one from ubuntu here http://www.ubuntu.com/phone/devices its only 169 euro so worth it in my opinion.